# byte[] to XML with .NET/C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML stored in the database as a byte array (byte[]). Now I need to get that byte array from the database which I'm successfully doing and pass it to XDocument like the following:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> ReadFromByte(byte[] UserData, string toplevelnode, string firstattribute, string secondattribute)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(UserData);
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = doc.Descendants(toplevelnode).ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute(firstattribute).Value,
                                                               x => x.Attribute(secondattribute).Value);
            return dictionary;
        }
```

This code works fine if I pass to XDocument a file on the server in XML format. However it doesn't work if I pass a byte[] array.

Any hint how I should conert byte[] array back to XML would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you store xml document in database? using serialization or just using bytes of the xml content?

Comment: You should be able to write the db field value to a MemoryStream and feed that stream to the XDocument.

Comment: Yes, how you get the XML out of the Database all depends on how you got it in there in the first place. You need to tell us how you got it into the database.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work - is an exception thrown - if so then what is it?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting Could not find file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\System.IO.MemoryStream'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream(UserData, false))
  {
     var doc = Xdocument.Load(stream);

     ...
  }
```

As @int3 asked, we should know the enocoding (UTF8/16, etc) that you used to store the document in the database.

Comment: I've written the XML into a memory stream like the following: MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            ms.Position = 0;

            XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8); Then reading the memory stream into a byte array like the following: byte[] biteArray = new byte[ms.Length];
            
                ms.Read(biteArray, 0, (int)ms.Length);

Comment: Ok, my answer should then work; because the document in the DB should start with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> and XDocument.Load will read it correctly.

Comment: If I do like you did, passing stream directly to the XDocument, I'm getting "Can't convert stream to string." And if I do like the following: Xdocument.Load(stream).ToString(), I'll get Could not find file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\System.IO.MemoryStream'.

Comment: Ok, you are using .Net 3.5 **not** .Net 4.0.  Change `.Load(stream)` to `.Load(new XmlTextReader(stream))`

Comment: Thanks, it passed, but now I'm getting The following exception: "Root element is missing."

Comment: @cycero: `MemoryStream`s have a method called `ToArray()` to return a byte array with all the data; use that instead of `ms.Read(...)`

Comment: ... Not that I expect that to actually solve your problem. Are you sure the byte array you're supplying is not empty? "Root element is missing" means just that - the stream is empty.

Comment: It is not empty. Its capacity shows 41810 but still shows "Root element is missing".

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got it working. Actually the problem was not exactly in the "reading" but "writing" part.